# wordpress post_excerpt length limit 15

Tags: wordpress, function, post, limit

I wanted limit my post_excerpt length 15 and here is :

```
    function expert_shortcode($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array('title' => '','category' => ''), $atts, 'expert' ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(
        array('category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'post_type' => 'post')
        );

        $list = '<div class="left_top"><h3 class="left_top_title"> '.$title.'</h3>';
    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    //get the ID of your post in the loop
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $post_excerpt = get_post_meta($id, 'post_excerpt', true);  
    $post_thumbnail=get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail');    
    $list .= '

                <div class="left_top ">
                    '.$post_thumbnail.'
                    <h3><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>
                    <p>'.$post_excerpt.'</p>
                </div>

    ';        
endwhile;
$list.= '</div>';
wp_reset_query();
return $list;
}

add_shortcode('expert', 'expert_shortcode');
```

Its working with custom field input, But I wanted limit word length 15.

Answer (score 3):

Since, you are using a custom field we will have to write a function of our own. Anyways, PHP is pretty cool and gives us [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Here's how we will do it:

```
function custom_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    $parts = explode( $excerpt, ' ', 15 ); // explode string after 15 spaces
    return $parts[0]; // taking the first part of the array
}
```

---

If you were using [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt), you could have written a filter to control length:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: user has not mentioned word in question

Comment: @BhumiShah if you read the question carefully, the last line says "Its working with custom field input, But I wanted limit word length 15." Moreover, I assume it to limit because `excerpt_length` implies word limit and not character limit.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
substr($post_excerpt, 0, 15);
```

limit with words

```
 $words = explode(' ', $post_excerpt);
 echo implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 15));
```

your code would be like

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_post_order_in_admin' );

 function expert_shortcode($atts){
extract( shortcode_atts( array('title' => '','category' => ''), $atts, 'expert' ) );

$q = new WP_Query(
    array('category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'post_type' => 'post')
    );

    $list = '<div class="left_top"><h3 class="left_top_title"> '.$title.'</h3>';
while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
//get the ID of your post in the loop
$id = get_the_ID();
$post_excerpt = get_post_meta($id, 'post_excerpt', true);  
 $words = explode(' ', $post_excerpt);
$data=implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 15));
$post_thumbnail=get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail');    
$list .= '

            <div class="left_top ">
                '.$post_thumbnail.'
                <h3><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>
                <p>'.$data.'</p>
            </div>

';        
endwhile;
 $list.= '</div>';
wp_reset_query();
  return $list;
}

 add_shortcode('', 'expert_shortcode');
```

Comment: You code will return the string with only 15 characters and not 15 words.

Comment: No. I don't want it. The OP does. And yes, it seems like your corrected answer will work but it could have been done in a easier way by using the third parameter used by explode. `explode( $string, $delimiter, $limit )`. See my answer for that approach.

Comment: Bhumi Shah, How will work this:<div class="left_top_news floatleft">
     '.$post_thumbnail.'
     <h3><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>
     <p>'.$post_excerpt, 0, 15.'</p>
</div>

Comment: $words = explode(' ', $post_excerpt);
 
<div class="left_top_news floatleft"> '.$post_thumbnail.' <h3><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3> <p>'.implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 15)).'</p> </div>

Comment: Bhumi Shah: after added your code it shown:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', $post_excerpt); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) functions.php on line 285 was= '.$post_thumbnail.'

Comment: It's working fine here  and i have updated code. pl check above

Comment: Thanks a lot to Bhumi Shah and Aniket, Its Working now :)

Comment: Yes Bhumi, I got solution.